# segyio > How do I solve ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python

My goal is to read a SGY Header file to extract weathering velocity in a bulk of files I have in a repo.  Working in windows 10 and using the code below I was just testing the functionality of the segyio (version = '1.9.0' installed using conda forge), but I got the following error:

```
import segyio  
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

pth = r"D:\Documents - D drive\2020\aaa\bbb\ccc.SGY"  
segyfile = segyio.open(pth, ignore_geometry=True)  
segyfile
```

**Traceback:**

```
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-dea1e137903b> in <module>
      1 pth = r"D:\Documents - D drive\2020\aaa\bbb\ccc.SGY"
----> 2 segyfile = segyio.open(pth, ignore_geometry=True)
      3 # segyfile

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\segyio\open.py in open(filename, mode, iline, xline, strict, ignore_geometry, endian)
    159         raise ValueError(problem.format(endian) + opts)
    160 
--> 161     from . import _segyio
    162     fd = _segyio.segyiofd(str(filename), mode, endians[endian])
    163     fd.segyopen()

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

After a quick look into github, there are a couple of mentions (#483 and #435) about same error message but any of them could help me to solve this error, in #421 says "Problem solved by installing version 1.9.0a1", where can I download that version to test? or maybe you have a more recent approach or suggestion on how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.9.3 solve the issue.